# Why me subscribe method in angular is not working?

Tags: node.js, angular, observable, subscribe

I'm new in Angular, Nodejs and I was doing a CRUD app of txt files 
I have to list all the files in a list, if you click one file need to display the data on a 'P'aragraph
**My document component** 
getDocuments() - returns an array of all files in a path
getOneDOcument(name) -> get all the data of a file given "name" 
getData(name) -> have to send the data to the paragraph with the id _> "paragraph_content"

```
  getDocuments(){
    this.DocumentService.getDocuments()
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.DocumentService.documents = res as Document[]
          console.log("dentro del susbcribe");
          console.log(res);
        });
    console.log("Fuera del subscribe");
  }

  getOneDocument(name : String){
    console.log("NOO");

    this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name).subscribe(res => {
            this.DocumentService.documentSelected = res as Document;          
            console.log("."); 
        });

  }

  getData(name : String){
    console.log("hello name -> " , name)
    // document.getElementById("paragraph_content").innerHTML = this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name)

    console.log("Before the subscrie");
    this.DocumentService.getOneDocument(name)
        .subscribe( (res ) =>{
          //I need to change the paragraph content like this
          //document.getElementById("paragraph_content").innerHTML = res.toString() Not working
          console.log("Within", res);
        } )
    console.log("After Subscribe ")
  }
```

*Document Service* 
I got the arrays of the url given

```
  getDocuments(){
    console.log("Get Documents method");

   return this.http.get(this.URL_API );
  }
  getOneDocument(name: String){
    console.log("Get OneDocyment method name given: " , name);
    return this.http.get(this.URL_API + `/${name}`)
  }

  postDocument(){
   //left
  }

  deleteDocument(name:String){
   //left
  }
```

*Document Component html*

```
<nav>
        <ul class="ds-list-unstyled" *ngFor="let document of DocumentService.documents">
            <li><a href="#" (click)="getData(document)"> {{document}}  </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <article>
        <h2>Texto en pantalla: </h2>
        <p id="paragraph_content">Needs to change with a click
        </p>

    </article>
```

And the responde that I got when I click a file is:
[image: Image1:]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error in the browser doesn't show much, try to expand it .. BTW, you should handle errors in subscribe, it is pretty helpful .. `.subscribe((value) => {...}, (error) => {...});`

Comment: [link] (https://imgur.com/CMKxkhC) @cabesuon That's what I get :/

Comment: Another way tou can try is that set response to the variable and use that variable to bind the attribute innerHtml property using angular's attribute binding. What this will do is whenever you cange the value of variable on .ts file angular will automatically update the content of paragraph. You can set variable before console.log() in getData() -> subscribe()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMLHttpRequest property responseType is an enumerated string value specifying the type of data contained in the response. It also lets the author change the response type.
You should set the responseType to text.

Try like this

```
getOneDocument(name: String){
    console.log("Get OneDocyment method name given: " , name);
    const requestOptions: Object = {
     responseType: 'text'
   }  
   return this.http.get(`${this.URL_API}/${name}`,requestOptions )

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is that you are not specifying that the data is text, that is why is trying to convert to JSON.

Try adding the `responseType` to the request, something like this,

```
getOneDocument(name: String){
    return this.http.get(`${this.URL_API}/${name}`, {responseType: 'text'})
  }
```

Comment: OMG...  I thought the problem was in the document component I spent around half day with that problem, I thought my document service was working fine... Thank you so much...  @cabesuon

Comment: Glad it helps you!